# Is there a driver for a hub?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, hub

Is there a driver for  a hub/switch?
So that I can control the flow of data from the other computer that currently uses bandwidth, so that I could get higher bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need a router of some sort to do the bandwidth management you're talking about.

If you already have a DSL/Cable router, you might be able to use [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) to get the function you seek. But that's not for the faint of heart and may wind up destroying your router.

Comment: Or a managed switch should also work.

Comment: Any Linux system with two NICs junctioned to a virtual bridge interface, with appropriate `tc` QoS policies applied to the virtual bridge interface, would also work.  Tomato or DD-WRT is this.  Defintely not for the faint of heart but you will learn a lot.  It won't destroy your router - you can always reset it to restore configuration.